# Kafka Streams: Can I subscribe my processor to multiple topics with different number of partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to create a Kafka Stream Topology with multiple processors that subscribe to a regex pattern and multiple topics as a result.

For example, pattern `topic_(?:a|b|c)` will connect to topic_a, topic_b, and topic_c. I have a different number of partitions for each topic, since they have different loads. When running my topology, though, I see:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException
...
Topics not co-partitioned
```

The difference between them are:

```
topic_a: 3 partitions
topic_b: 3 partitions
topic_c: 30 partitions
```

Am I allowed to do this, or when subscribing to multiple topics I need to maintain the same number of partitions?

Into further context, each of the topics listed above are actually two, like topic_a1 and topic_a2, topic_b1 and topic_b2. They all got the same partition number and I’m trying to join, and later aggregate them using the streams API

Comment: Yes, you can subscribe, but what other actions does your topology do?

Comment: It tries to join two topics. For instance: topic_a1 and topic_a1 (both with same number of partitions), topic_b1 and topic_b2, and so on

Comment: How do you prevent a1 and b2 from joining? I think that's the problem

Comment: They do not share the same keys. So a1 and b1 wouldn’t be joined I suppose?

Comment: That doesn't mean the topology doesn't think the topics should not be joined at all, though. It still would need to consume both, therefore all possible pairs of topics would need the same partition count

Comment: Humm isn’t there any way around that?

Comment: Other than running separate applications / topologies, not that I'm aware of

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

If an application is subscribed to multiple topics using a pattern, all of the topics need to have the same number of partitions.